# apply a function several times (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna use tabs here, several times
    `[http://lab.infographizm.com/jquery/onglets/onglets-verticaux/][1]`     
but it doesn't work
Can you help me ?

here, is a JSFiddle with two system working with the same javascript with working errors.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afwzkqpc/3)

Comment: Please provide your code *here* and describe the question more clearly.

Comment: What browser isn't this working in? The tabs at your URL seem to be working in Firefox. The first set of tabs on the fiddle also seem to work, though the second set of tabs doesn't seem to. Is that the problem you're asking about?

Comment: Make sure for each set of tags, everything has unique ids

Comment: And here was my mistake ! Thank you for your help, I guess it was easier than I imagined !

Comment: You can actually do this with just CSS, which would be a way better solution, since users without JS could still use the site properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same ID twice for your `div` elements, as well as the `href` values for the `a` tags.

See my JSFiddle fork: http://jsfiddle.net/ubzup7h0/

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear but basically one issue you are going to have to fix in order to get multiple tabs working is you need *unique* identifiers for each section. In your case, the following snippet is an example of what needs to change

```
<div class="tabs-onglets">
    <a href="#lundi">Lundi</a>
    <a href="#mardi">Mardi</a>
    <a href="#mercredi">Mercredi</a>
    <a href="#jeudi">Jeudi</a>
</div>
<div id="contenu">
    <div id="lundi">...</div>
    <!-- other tabs -->
</div>

<!-- then the second set also needs unique ids -->
<div class="tabs-onglets">
    <a href="#1lundi">Lundi</a>
    <a href="#1mardi">Mardi</a>
    <a href="#1mercredi">Mercredi</a>
    <a href="#1jeudi">Jeudi</a>
</div>
<div id="contenu">
    <div id="1lundi">...</div>
    <!-- other tabs -->
</div>
```

See this working in a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/afwzkqpc/4/).